# Python 3+ import package in a function call?

Tags: python

Overtime I have built up a collection of utility functions for various things.

I would like to put them all in package, with a bit more structure than just a single file containing all the functions.

Some of these functions are written assuming certain packages have been imported e.g. I have several `numpy` and `pandas` utility functions that assume something like `import numpy as np`

Obviously I will not use this hypothetical package like `from <pkg> import *` but I do not want to hinder performance either.

So if I have a `numpy` utility function, should I add this to every function

```
# mypkg.np.utils
import sys

def np_util_fn(...):
    if 'np' not in sys.modules: import numpy as np
    # rest of func
```

or

```
# mypkg.np.utils
import sys
if 'np' not in sys.modules: import numpy as np    

def np_util_fn(...):
    # rest of func
```

which is more performant if I use a different part of this package? e.g. `from pkg.other.utils import fn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's analyze your issue. Assume you have a file `module.py`:

```
print("Module got imported")
```

and a file `test.py` with:

```
import module
import module
```

. If you now execute `test.py` you will get

```
Module got imported
```

. Please note that this line is not outputted two times. This means that python already checks whether a module was already imported (before reimporting it). So your check `if 'np' not in sys.modules: import numpy as np` is not needed. This check only delays things as it may result in a double check.

In case you want to reimport a module you need `reload(module)`. So if you have

```
import module
import module
reload(module)
```

in `code.py` you will see the line `Module got imported` two times.

This means that

```
import numpy as np
```

is sufficient. There is no need to check whether it already got imported via:

```
if 'np' not in sys.modules: import numpy as np
```

It depends whether it is advantageous to do `import numpy as np` at the very beginning of your script or in a function. If the function is executed multiple times, it is advantageous to do so only at the very beginning. Otherwise you are rechecking whether 'np' is not in sys.modules all the time. In contrast if you can argue that your function is not called to often / is not necessarily executed in your program (e.g. because it depends on user input) then it may be advantageous (seen from the "point vu" of speed) to import this module in a function only.

I normally don't use any `import` statements in functions as I always have the feeling that they blow up the function body and thus reduce readability.