# Is it good practice to load large objects in one file and import them in other Python files?

Tags: python, import

I recently realized, in a Python project, that I need to load a number of objects that are quite significant in size (perhaps Gigabytes...)

It seems I have two choices:

1. Load them in my top-level file and pass them on to functions that need them. But that could easily get annoyingly tiresome **if many functions need to access many large objects**.
2. Load all large objects in one file and import those needed on demand in any Python file across the project. Now this seems neat enough. I would have something like this in a `large_objects.py` file:

   ```
   huge_file_1 = load_huge_file_1()
   huge_file_2 = load_huge_file_2()
   huge_file_3 = load_huge_file_3()
   ```

Now, I'm not sure if the second approach efficient enough. For example, will the Python interpreter execute load_huge_file_i() every time something is imported.

Also, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359054/python-3-import-package-in-a-function-call/53359141#53359141 the python interpreter is not necessarily reloading the file once it was already loaded.

Comment: Cool! So, the second approach is a good practice?

Comment: I provided the link in order to provide background information. Having huge data blocks in code is not seen as good practice in any programming language. Data should be separated from code. Nevertheless I still would prefer your second way (in case someone would ask me which way is less bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of considerations. So firstly, anything that's just flat in a file will be executed when the file is imported, which is usually immediately. So I often do my loading upfront in my files. But it doesn't have to be in one location. You can do this in many different files. For example:

Slow:

```
from nltk.corpus import words

def check_word(word):
    return word in words.words():    # gets executed on every call
```

Fast:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
WORDS = frozenset(words.words())   # Only gets executed once
def check_word(word):
    return word in WORDS
```

Another consideration however is memory. If you load a lot of objects into memory early on you will carry them around even when they aren't being used. Python uses reference counting, not garbage collection, which means that if there is any remaining reference to an object it will stay in memory. Consider

```
# Inefficient memory usage
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('second.csv')
do_something(df_1)
do_something(df_2)
df_1.to_csv('output1.csv')
df_2.to_csv('output2.csv')
# Efficient memory usage
df_1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
do_something(df_1)
df_1.to_csv('output1.csv')    # Last reference to df_1. dropped from memory here
df_2 = read_csv('second.csv')   # Only df_2 in memory now
do_something(df_2)
df_2.to_csv('output2.csv')
```

In other words, a key question to ask yourself is "how much of my data needs to be in memory at the same time, or how much can I break the problem down into independent problems", and then you can batch your processing to be memory efficient.

Loading up large objects in one location is fine but I don't think necessary for efficiency. You just want to make sure that you aren't doing multiple loads of anything in a loop (for example, executing the same SQL query over and over). Put that at a module level, or if you are using classes, then do it at initialization.

My usual pipeline is that I have an input/ output layer, a transform layer, and a controller. The controller calls for files usually early on, and then forwards them to be processed. But the work that I do is usually synchronous, so I can easily have a controller know what's going on. If you have an asynchronous project, then as you say this pipeline might get out of hand. Having one file to handle uploads I think is fairly common. But it might not even be necessary, as explained, just make sure it happens at a module level or at initialisation of a class.