# Python: Importing a large function only when needed

Tags: python, import, nlp

I want to use `spacy` in my module for some natural language processing. I can load the function `nlp` as

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

which takes a long time because the database is nearly 1gb. Suppose the above code is in the file `nlp_file.py`. If I want to use the function `nlp` in my module importing using `from nlp_file import nlp`, I can do one of a few things:

1. Load it when my module is imported in the `__init__.py` file.
2. Load it at the beginning of each file that uses it.
3. Load only when I need to call `nlp`.

I think that 3 is the best option here, but goes against all my python instincts to put import statements at the top of files. If I put it in  `__init__.py` then everytime I want to use part of my module that doesn't require nlp I will take a massive performance hit. If I load it at the beginning of each file that uses it, I will have the same problem. Therefore it makes most sense to import at the beginning of functions and classes that require nlp.

Am I correct in believing this? Is there a better way to use `nlp` in different parts of my module? Thank you in advance!

Similar question: [Is it good practice to load large objects in one file and import them in other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359891/is-it-good-practice-to-load-large-objects-in-one-file-and-import-them-in-other-p)

Comment: Maybe this can help? This module allows lazy-loading, so you'll actually import its content only on function call. Note `lazy_callable` method. https://pypi.org/project/lazy-import/

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for pointing me towards it! So something like `nlp = lazy_import.lazy_callable("nlp_file.nlp")` at the top of each file that needs it?

Comment: From manual:
"Finally, if you want to mark some modules and submodules your package imports as always being lazy, it is as simple as lazily importing them at the root __init__.py level. Other files can then import all modules normally, and those that have already been loaded as lazy in __init__.py will remain so".

If you have __init__.py, than you can just lazy-import it there and use normal import in all other files. Looks like a very useful feature...